# Avoiding obstacle of a car robot using IR

Tags: wheeled-robot, electronics

I am using an IR sensor which detects the obstacle. My question is how does 2 robots stops on a finish line which is an object higher that the height of the car robot if i am using IR, comparator(LM741),Relay, bjt, diode And Hbridge (L293d) ? 
How to detect the egde? If detected what it does ?
How to detect obstacle ? And how to detect the finish line which is  the an object higher in height?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* William, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. Please also focus your post to a single question.  We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Could you draw a simple picture of the situation?